# Dynamic updating of Activex Textbox entries

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4 activex text boxes in which values (numbers) are entered.  The 5th text box is the sum of the first 4 text box entries. I want the 5th text box to update dynamically when the value in one or more of the first 4 text box values is changed by a user.  The first 4 boxes are named "TextBox1, TextBox2..., and the 5th is TextBox5. What would be the code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the change event to detect when a text box was changed and then add the values up.  A text box by default has strings so you'll also need to convert values to numeric (integers, doubles, long, etc)

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Sum
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Sum
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
    Sum
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox4_Change()
    Sum
End Sub

Private Sub Sum()
    TextBox5.Value = Int(TextBox1) + Int(TextBox2.Value) + Int(TextBox3.Value) + Int(TextBox4.Value)
End Sub
```

---

You'll probably want some error checking to avoid debug errors.  Here is one way to check that `TextBox1` has a numeric value in it.

```
Private Sub Sum()
    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1) Then
        TextBox5.Value = "Error in Box 1"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    TextBox5.Value = Int(TextBox1) + Int(TextBox2.Value) + Int(TextBox3.Value) + Int(TextBox4.Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: PERFECT!! That fixed my issue like a charm.  Just one more question.  Instead of adding the values,I changed the code to multiply the values. The result in TextBox5 displays a number with several numeric characters right of the decimal point.  How can I reduce the displayed product to just two spaces to the right of the decimal point?

Comment: You can round to 2 significant figures like this: `TextBox1.Value = Round(TextBox1.Value, 2)`

Comment: You, sir, are a genius.  I hope you don't mind me picking your brain.  I'm trying to learn coding and I'm literally starting from square one.  Thank you for your help.  I'm sure I'll have other questions in the future.